# How to change json data format from array to array of objects with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ag-grid

I am trying to load data into `ag-grid` so I got the json data like this format:

```
{"my_data":{"labels":[1,2,3,...], "idx":["idx1", "idx2", ...]}}
```

I need it to be like this to pass it to the grid:

```
{"my_data":[{"labels": 1}, {"labels": 2}, ..., {"idx":"idx1"}, {"idx":"idx2"}, ...}]
```

Is there a fast way to do it this format or I have to loop through the data using `reduce` or `map` ?

desired format example: https://www.ag-grid.com/sample-data/monthlySales.json

I tried to load the data like this

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
gridOptions.api.setRowData(obj.mydata.labels);
```

Comment: you you need it in this format or corresponding indices in same objects? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: I dont understand you

Comment: do you really need all new objects in a single array?

Comment: each column/field in its own arrary

Comment: please update the question and add the wanted format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` will simplify.

```js
const data = { my_data: { labels: [1, 2, 3], idx: ["idx1", "idx2"] } };

const updated = Object.entries(data.my_data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  value.forEach(item => acc.push({ [key]: item }));
  return acc;
}, []);

const data_updated = { my_data: updated };

console.log(data_updated);
```